# A concrete description of the projective tensor product of Lipschitz spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, lipschitz-spaces

$\newcommand{\projtenprod}[2]{#1 \; \hat\otimes_\pi #2}$
$\DeclareMathOperator\Lip{Lip}\DeclareMathOperator\AE{AE}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\| #1\|}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{| #1|}$

**Background** 
***Projective tensor product.*** Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Let
$$
X \otimes Y := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \bigcup_{\substack{x_i \in X \\y_i \in Y}}\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i \otimes y_i}
$$
denote their algebraic tensor product. The projective tensor product $\projtenprod{X}{Y}$ is the completion of the algebraic tensor product with respect to the projective norm
$$
\pi(u) := \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \norm{x_i} \, \norm{y_i} \colon u = \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i \otimes y_i} \right\},
$$
where the infimum is taken over all representations of the tensor $u = \sum_{i=1}^n {x_i \otimes y_i}$.

The projective tensor product is given by (Ryan, "Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach spaces", Prop. 2.8)
$$
\projtenprod{X}{Y} = \bigcup_{\substack{x_i \in X \\y_i \in Y}}\sum_{i=1}^\infty {x_i \otimes y_i},
$$
and
$$
\pi(u) = \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \norm{x_i} \, \norm{y_i} \colon u = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {x_i \otimes y_i} \right\},
$$
where the infimum is taken over all representations of the tensor $u = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {x_i \otimes y_i}$.

If $X$ itself is a dual space with a predual $X^\diamond$, and either $X$ or $Y$ has the [approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property), then the projective tensor product $\projtenprod{X}{Y}$ can be identified with the space of nuclear operators $\mathcal N(X^\diamond,Y)$.

***Space of Lipschitz functions.*** Let $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ be compact and $e \in D$. Denote by $\Lip_0(D)$ the space of all Lipschitz functions on $D$ (with respect to the Euclidean metric $d(p,q) := \norm{p-q}$, $p,q \in D$) vanishing at $e$, equipped with the following norm
$$
\|f\|_{\Lip_0} := \sup_{\substack{p,q \in D \\ p \neq q}} \frac{\abs{f(p)-f(q)}}{d(p,q)}.
$$

For $0<\alpha<1$, denote by $D^\alpha$ the metric space $(D,d^\alpha)$, where $d^\alpha(p,q) := \norm{p-q}^\alpha$. By $\Lip_0(D^\alpha)$ we will denote the space of Lipschitz functions with respect to the metric $d^\alpha$.

The space $\Lip_0(D)$ (resp. $\Lip_0(D^\alpha)$) has a unique predual, called the Arens-Eells space $\AE(D)$ (resp. $\AE(D^\alpha)$), also known as the Lipschitz-free space.
It is known (Nik Weaver, "Lipschitz Algebras", 2nd ed., Thm. 8.49) that $\AE(D^\alpha)$ is linearly homeomorphic to $\ell^1$, and $\Lip_0(D^\alpha)$ to $\ell^\infty$ if $0<\alpha<1$. In this case, $\Lip_0(D^\alpha)$ also has a second predual $\mathrm{lip}_0(D^\alpha)$ (so-called little Lipschitz functions), which is linearly homeomorphic to $c_0$.

$\ $

**Question**
Is there a concrete description of the projective tensor product $\projtenprod{\Lip_0(D)}{\Lip_0(D)}$ or $\projtenprod{\Lip_0(D^\alpha)}{\Lip_0(D^\alpha)}$ in terms of Lipschitz functions on $D \times D$?

***Thoughts***
There is a canonical identification of $\Lip_0(D \times D)$ with the space of vector-valued Lipschitz functions $\Lip_0(D,\Lip_0(D))$, which in its turn can be identified with the space of bounded linear operators $\mathcal L(\AE(D),\Lip_0(\Omega))$. With the inclusion $\mathcal N(\AE(D),\Lip_0(\Omega)) \subset \mathcal L(\AE(D),\Lip_0(\Omega))$, we have
$$
\Lip_0(D \times D) = \Lip_0(D,\Lip(D)) = \mathcal L(\AE(D),\Lip_0(\Omega)) \\\supset  \mathcal N(\AE(D),\Lip_0(D)) = \projtenprod{\Lip_0(D)}{\Lip(D)}.
$$
If $g \in \Lip_0(D \times D)$ is a Lipschitz function, is there an intuitive condition on $g$ so that $g \in \projtenprod{\Lip_0(D)}{\Lip_0(D)}$ holds?

$\ $

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: To identify the projective tensor product with the space of nuclear operators requires the approximation property.

Comment: Have you looked at $D=[0,1]$? Here $\mathrm{Lip}_0(D)$ is isometric to $L_\infty(D)$.

Comment: This is a good question, I'd like to know the answer too!

Comment: I wonder if the same question has an answer for $C(D)$ in place of $Lip_0(D)$. Let's also assume that $D$ is hyperstonean so that $C(D)$ is a dual Banach algebra.

Comment: @OnurOktay It is known that $C(D \times D)$ can be identified with the injective tensor product $C(D) \, \hat \otimes_\varepsilon \, C(D)$. I am not sure about the projective product

Comment: @DirkWerner Thank you for noticing, I have edited the post now

Comment: Can we also identify $Lip_0(D\times D)$ with $Lip_0(D)\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} Lip_0(D)$? If so, does the analogy with the $C(D)$ answer the question above up to some extent?

Comment: @OnurOktay On pp. 49-50 in his book, Ryan shows that $C(D,X)$ can be idetified with $C(D) \, \hat \otimes_\varepsilon \, X$ for any Banach space $X$, but this involves a density argument which may fail for $Lip_0$ since it is non-separable. I haven't checked, though

Comment: @NikWeaver Is there at least a way to check for a given function $g \in Lip_0(D \times D)$ that $g \in Lip_0(D) \, \hat \otimes_\pi \, Lip_0(D)$?

Comment: @DirkWerner I'm also not sure what $L^\infty([0,1]) \, \hat \otimes_\pi \, L^\infty([0,1])$ would look like. Or even $\ell^\infty \, \hat \otimes_\pi \ell^\infty$, for that matter

Comment: No idea. I've never thought about projective tensor products of Lipschitz spaces --- I would expect injective tensor products to be more natural (but I haven't thought about them either).

Comment: $\ell^{\infty}\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}\ell^{\infty}$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ are not linearly isomorphic. Thus, $Lip_0(D)\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} Lip_0(D) \neq Lip_0(D\times D)$ whenever both $Lip_0(D)$ and $Lip_0(D\times D)$ are both isomorphic to $\ell^{\infty}$ for some $D$. This doesn't make the question above any harder or easier though.

Comment: Did you consider to adapt the atomic decompositions of the classical Hölder spaces $C^{\alpha}$ to $Lip(D\times D)$ for common (e.g., Lipschitz domain) $D$? Please see Triebel's monographs, for instance Chapter 2 in *"The theory of Function spaces III"*. In the same book, you can find atomic decompositions for more general sets (see Ch. 8). Perhaps this method won't characterize the projective tensor product, but provide various (perhaps non-closed) subspaces that can be characterized via their atoms, for example, the Besov spaces $B_{1,1}^{s}$ for $s\geq\alpha$.

Comment: @OnurOktay Thank you! This actually could be something, since a certain type of wavelets form a basis in $lip_0(D^\alpha)$, hence a possible connection to Besov spaces (see [here](https://eudml.org/doc/292220) as well as Section 8.5 in Weaver's book). Thank you for the reference, I will look into this.

Comment: @OnurOktay Many thanks for the reference, Onur. For $\alpha<1$, it is indeed easy to show that $B_{1,1}^\alpha(D \times D) \subset Lip_0(D^\alpha) \hat \otimes_\pi Lip_(D^\alpha)$. There doesn't seem to be an equality, though. My intuition is that it could be the space of functions that are in $B_{1,1}^\gamma(D \times D)$ for all $\gamma<\alpha$, i.e. a conjecture could be that $Lip_0(D^\alpha) \hat \otimes_\pi Lip_(D^\alpha) = \bigcap_{0<\gamma<\alpha} B_{1,1}^\gamma(D \times D)$. Are you aware of any results in this direction?

Comment: $\ell^{\infty}\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^{\infty}$ contains a complemented copy of $\ell^2$, whereas $B^{\alpha}_{1,1}$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$ as a Banach space. I don't think your conjecture holds.

Comment: @OnurOktay ok, thanks.